Decode Jupiter route instruction data
I'm trying to decode a route instruction using the Jupiter V6 IDL.
The hex data is: e517cb977ae3ad2a010000001a640001003fc6b800000000e214e91a00000000030000
and I get something like:

RouteArgs { routePlan: [RoutePlanStep { swap: RaydiumClmm, percent:
100, inputIndex: 0, outputIndex: 1 }], inAmount: 3100000000,
quotedOutAmount: 451482850, slippageBps: 3, platformFeeBps: 0 }

How do I use inputIndex and outputIndex to get the input and output tokens?
